# How do I process the data submitted from HTML Form?

Tags: html, perl, cgi

I have written code to create a form to select multiple values. Below are some lines of my code to create a form to select multiple values.

```
my $parser = Text::CSV->new();
open($csv_fh, '<', $csv_file) or die $!;
my @headers = $parser->column_names( $parser->getline($csv_fh) );
print <<"EOF";
<FORM ACTION=$ENV{'SCRIPT_NAME'} METHOD=POST>
<TR><TD VALIGN=TOP><B>Type<BR></B></TD>
<SELECT NAME="$header" MULTIPLE>
EOF
                foreach my $header (@headers) {
                        chomp($header);
                        print "<OPTION VALUE=\"$header\">$header</OPTION>";
                }
                print <<"EOF";
</SELECT></TD></TR>
<CENTER><INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE=SUBMIT></CENTER>
<INPUT TYPE=HIDDEN NAME=action VALUE=procnew>
EOF
```

I need help on if i select 4 values, then how to read those values and make use of that.

Also, please advise if there is any option to restrict the selection of values. For example, I want to restrict to select max 5 values only and min 1 should be selected from this form.

Comment: It is difficult to answer this question since you don't seem to have even started writing the part which deals with the return values.

Perhaps you can Google for some information on writing CGI scripts.

Comment: Some issues in the shown code: there seems to be a misplaced closing brace on the third line, and the ACTION attribute of the FORM seems not to be enclosed in quotes.

Comment: @Svante: I have corrected the first one. Can you please explain more on ACTION attribute.

Comment: <FORM ACTION=$ENV{'SCRIPT_NAME'} METHOD=POST> should be <FORM ACTION="$ENV{'SCRIPT_NAME'}" METHOD="POST">

Comment: @lexu: No changes after doing this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're asking a big question that involves many newbie level concepts. I think you should go through some HTML form and CGI tutorials. That will probably answer many of your questions.

The CGI.pm module can help you process the form. You can handle the data anyway that you like.